# Problem with boot manager

Tags: boot, grub2, windows

I have installed Windows, after that I have installed Ubuntu. I logged in to Ubuntu, everything was ok. Then I logged in to Windows and after that Ubuntu boot manager was gone, I couldn't get into Ubuntu. In order to fix this, I clicked something stupid in Windows like "Solve problems with booting" which probably made the situation worse. I can't boot to Ubuntu, it automatically loads Windows. I can't even go to Bios because Windows is so stupid.

I created something like this with Ubuntu Boot-Repair. They told me to share it with you:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/HHrRvZ74Gk/

Are you able to tell me what I should do to fix this basing on this?

Comment: First try the selected repair and suggestion on turning off Secure Boot in UEFI. Make sure fast start up is off in Windows also: http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions  What model Lenovo? You have a lot of duplicate UEFI entries. Best to remove some. To see entries `sudo efibootmgr -v` and then to delete: `sudo efibootmgr -b XXXX -B` for more details see `man efibootmgr`

Comment: Lenovo G510. Thanks for your help.

Comment: are you using a uefi or legacy bios?. if uefi, windows probably might have messed up the efi partition so it boots first.

Answer (score 0):

And you couldnt fix it with Boot-Repair? I did it already several times and it worked fine. Just follow the steps Boot-Repair tells you. In any case, disable the fast start up of Windows...this was already once my problem. I hope you know how?